# PSExec can not connect from Windows XP to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop, psexec

I am currently trying to use Remote Desktop on a Windows 7 Pro PC whose screen is currently broken from my old Windows XP laptop.
However, before the screen broke, remote connection was turned off on both machines.

After searching all evening, I tried to remotly enable Remote Desktop using PsExec, but it does not seem to be willing to connect to my remote machine and says "Access Denied" although I have spectified the right login/pass information explicitly.
The command I am trying to run looks like this:

```
psexec.exe -u MACHINE_NAME\ADMIN_LOGIN -p ADMIN_PASSWORD \\MACHINE_NAME cmd.exe
```

I then checked with Wireshark what login got sent, I noticed it was the one from my XP laptop, not the credentials I set with the above command, and immediatly after I received an "invalid login" packet.

Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do?

(Note that I still have physical access to the screenless machine and can try to use the command line, but without visual feedback, it's hard to tell if the action was successful or not, and I don't have another win7 machine to see what I should input)

EDIT: After searching some more, I found [this thread](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-doesnt-send-username_topic16324.html&ei=xprYUZKKMYS4hAfS0YGYDw&usg=AFQjCNGM-eTSIm2RUpn3tHibyYfTjEUhZA&sig2=kBQQRRcvw9zGdwWpBwM-9w&bvm=bv.48705608,d.ZG4&cad=rja) that gave me a solution to the wrong credentials issue. However, I still can't connect to my remote machine. The error I see from Wireshark traces is that I don't have the right to access the folder

```
\\[MACHINE_NAME]\ADMIN$
```

This is a bit odd since the account I'm logging with is an admin account on the remote machine...

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if \ADMIN$ is enabled on the remote PC? PsExec requires it, and that you have "full" file sharing, not just simple file sharing.
http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/psexec#comment-41670

You also want to make sure that you don't have any other connections between those PCs, e.g. opened a Windows Explorer window on \MACHINE_NAME. Otherwise any new connection may well use the same credentials as that existing one, i.e. your XP account rather than your Windows 7 account.

If sound is working, you might be able to use Windows 7 locally with Narrator reading window contents:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Hear-text-read-aloud-with-Narrator

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is because of the [UAC remote restrictions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016).
Basically - your remote session, even if being made with an administrator account - is not elevated, and so it gets no administrative permissions (such as required to use the *admin$* share).
You could try to connect to the machine remotely using regedit.exe, and set the **LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy** key that way, but I suspect the lack of elevation might scupper you there, too.
Unless the machine is in a domain, and you have a domain account which is also an administrator on the machine.
Assuming that any kind of administrative remote access is out of the question, your only hope might be to connect an external monitor to the broken laptop.